# Configure S3 client ServiceURL with AWSCredentials or RegionEndPoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, localstack

I'm trying to write an integration test for a service that uses the AmazonS3Client in order to upload files to amazon s3 buckets.
I am running an instance of localstack on http://localhost:4556
The problem I'm having is the code in the service is setting up the s3 clients the following way:

```
var region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(config.Region);
var client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, region);
```

I am able to set custom AWS Credentials using the following code:

```
const string ProfileName = "localstack";
            const string AccessKey = "foo";
            const string SecretKey = "goo";
            var profileOptions = new CredentialProfileOptions()
            {
                AccessKey = AccessKey,
                SecretKey = SecretKey,
            };
            var profile = new CredentialProfile(ProfileName, profileOptions);
            var file = new SharedCredentialsFile();
            file.RegisterProfile(profile);
            var profileManager = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();

            profileManager.RegisterProfile(profile);

            profileManager.TryGetProfile(ProfileName, out CredentialProfile profileResult);

            profileResult.Options.AccessKey = AccessKey;
            profileResult.Options.SecretKey = SecretKey;
            profileManager.RegisterProfile(profileResult);
```

Is there a way to make sure that the client that will be created will use my localstack instance as a server?

I tried looking for a way to configure the ServiceURL through the RegionEndPoint or AWSCredentials class but without any luck. I might have missed somehting.

Answer (score 1):

You can see here in the documentation some more informations about how to configure your client:

https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/sdks/dotnet/

There's this note:

> If you want to specify a region and credentials when creating the client, please set them as AuthenticationRegion and BasicAWSCredentials, like in this example:
>
> ```
> var lambdaClient = new AmazonLambdaClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("test", "test"), new AmazonLambdaConfig(
>    {
>        ServiceURL = "http://localhost:4566",
>        AuthenticationRegion = "eu-west-1"
>    }));
> ```
>
> ##### Note
>
> Make sure you are setting the `AuthenticationRegion` and not the `RegionEndpoint`. Setting the `RegionEndpoint` to a constant like `RegionEndpoint.EUWest1` will override the `ServiceURL`, and your request will end up against AWS.

Also, S3 is a bit specific in a sense, because of [virtual host addressed buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html) (as seen in this [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/7652#issuecomment-1424510263)). Using the example above, you could add `ForcePathStyle = true` to the config to be sure to not encounter any issue.

Using your example:

```
var config = new AmazonS3Config(
    {
        ServiceURL = "http://localhost:4566",
        AuthenticationRegion = config.region,
        ForcePathStyle = true
    }
);
var client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, config);
```